# connection a TM-T88V printer directly to an android tablet

Tags: android, printing, epson

We have a TM-T88V epson printer with ethernet which we connect to a number of android tablets. So the printer is connected to the network with ethernet, and the tablets are connected to the network with wifi, and printing is working fine.

But there are some use cases where we want to connect a android tablet directly to a printer, using either an ethernet cable or usb cable.

At first I thought usb would be the easy solutionp. Just plug it in and print. But our app uses ePOS-Print.jar to do printing and that seems to support only bluetooth and ethernet, not usb. Is this really true?

Ethernet is also a possibility. But then the issue is: How do I get an ip address for the printer? With the tablet connected directly to the printer there is no dhcp server, and I could not find any documentation for Epson printers about how to set the printer to a fixed ip.

Comment: In theory you could do something with a USB ethernet adapter and implementing an entire driver, network stack, DHCP server, and print library for it in an Android service against the Android USB host APIs (assuming those are supported on your device).  In practice a "pocket" router as a more portable form of your current setup is probably a better idea.  The DHCP server would run on the router.  Choosing one where you can replace the firmware could give you more flexibility.